# Conditional Formatting highlight the max with color based on column

Tags: vba, excel

I use excel 2013 and I want to highlight the **MAX** number value in **each row**

So with Conditional Formatting I use this formula :  `=A9=MAX($A9:$D9)` which is working fine.

Now the Max is colored By **Red**.

But I want the following if the max is in :

**A** column -> colored by **red**.
**B** column -> colored by **yellow**.
**C** column -> colored by **green**.
**D** column -> colored by **grey**.

Comment: Wouldn't you just do one conditional format per column then? I'm not sure what the question is...

Comment: no i want the max by row

Comment: meaning you want to highlight the largest number in Row 1, row 2, etc.?

Comment: yeah but the color of highlighting is based on column

Comment: So, if in Row 1, the max number is in column A, you want it to be red? If the max number in row 1 is in column B, you want it yellow, etc.?

Comment: yeah exactly :)

Comment: You will need four rules one for each column and change the max formula to suit.

Comment: What is the formula in O9

Comment: it's a mistake actually it is A9

Comment: So again just use four rules one for each column and change the formula.  So for column B it would be `=B9 = MAX($A9:$D9)` then the `B9` would change to `C9` for Column C And `D9` for D.